# "signed in successfully" appears more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I wanted to create a registration for users with devise in RoR. However when I login or logout the message "signed in successfully" or "signed out successfully" appears more than once. Any idea how this can happen?

Here is the view/layouts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Server</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track'=> 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track'=> 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>

<p class= "notice" ><%= notice %></p>
<p class= "alert" ><%= notice %></p>

<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're outputting `notice` twice... it's right there in the code.  Delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `<%= notice %>` in your application layout twice.